# Session values lost on opening new window through button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am opening a new window on button click from iframe and in background getting ajax call from plugin. But the problem is I am losing session values in new window. Can anyone provide me the solution with which I can keep the session's values persistent even in new window.
Here is a code in javascript file in application :

```
$(document).on('click', '#from_salesforce', function() {
    tabId=$("#tab_id").val();
    window.open("https://ap5.salesforce.com/home/home.jsp?amazon_tab_id="+tabId, "_blank");
});
```

Here is ajax call from plugin :

```
if(isSalesforceHomeTab(tabUrl) && isFromAmazonToSalesforce(tabUrl)){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://c09de501.ngrok.io/plugin/touches/salesforce_direct_from_amazon",
        data: {
            amazon_tab_id: amazon_tab_id,
            salesforce_tab_id: tabId
        },
        success:function(response){
        }
    });
}
```

Ajax call hit this function :

```
def salesforce_direct_from_amazon
    debugger
    session["is_direct_from_amazon_#{params['salesforce_tab_id']}"] = true
    session["amazon_tab_id_in_salesforce_tab_#{params['salesforce_tab_id']}"] = params[:amazon_tab_id]
    render json: {success: true} 
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to use a cookie most likely. Sessions are handled a bit differently.

```
cookies[:your_hash]
```